# Xamarin HttpClient.PostAsync gives a NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, android, node.js, http, xamarin

I am trying to connect a Xamarin Android app client to a Node.js server. The problem comes when I try to post data to the server, as the application gets blocked (without showing me where the error is) and the server doesn't receive data.

**Code:**

```
public static async Task<string> SendPostRequest(string request, string dataToServer)
    {
        var endpoint = $"https://192.168.0.123:5000";
        var content = new StringContent(dataToServer, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        using(var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(endpoint);
            var response = await client.PostAsync(request, content);
            return response.IsSuccessStatusCode ? await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync() : "";
        }
    }
```

**This is the Xamarin code:**

```
const sqlite = require('./database/db');
const express = require('express');
const session = require('express-session');
const path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const db_all = require('./database/better_db');
const dbFunctions = require('./database/functions');

const app = express();
app.set('views', './views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(session({
    secret: 'secret',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.get('/', function (request, response) {
    // Render login template
    response.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/login.html'));
});

app.post('/auth', async function (req, res) {
    let username = req.body.username;
    let password = req.body.password;
    if (username && password) {
        sqlite.get('SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE Name_Employee = ? and Password_Employee = ?', [username, password], (err, row) => {
            if (err) throw error;
            if (row) {
                req.session.username = username;
                req.session.loggedin = true;
                res.redirect('/home');
            } else {
                res.send("No user found with this credentials");
            }
            res.end();
        });
    } else {
        res.send('Please enter Username and Password!');
        res.end();
    }
});

app.post('/mobile', async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    res.send("ciao");
    res.end();
});

app.get('/home', async function (request, response) {
    // If the user is loggedin
    if (request.session.loggedin) {
        const lastOrder = await dbFunctions.getLastOrder();
        const numOrders = await dbFunctions.getOrdersNumber();
        const employees = await dbFunctions.getAllEmployees();
        response.render("home", {
            orders: lastOrder,
            username: request.session.username,
            numOrders: numOrders,
            employees: employees,
        });
    } else {
        // Not logged in
        //response.send('Please login to view this page!');
        response.redirect('/');
    }
    response.end();
});

app.get('/logout', async (request, response) => {
    if (request.session.loggedin) {
        delete request.session.username;
        response.json({result: 'SUCCESS'});
        //response.redirect('/');
    } else {
        response.json({result: 'ERROR', message: 'User is not logged in.'});
    }
});

app.listen(5000, () => "Server running on localhost:5000");
```

**This is the code for the Node.js server:**
[image]

Comment: Are you sure your device can connect to the server?  Try using the device browser to test.  Which line causes the exception?  What does the stack trace show?

Comment: `var response = await client.PostAsync(request, content);`
This is the line which causes the exception. I think the device can connect, if i use the device's browser i can connect to the server. I can't see any stack trace because it tells me that the error is from an external source code

Comment: Try creating a simple Get endpoint and see if you can connect to that.  And add a try/catch around your requests so you can examine the exception and see the stack trace